# Ubuntu 22.04 autorun.sh "Run Software" from external USB not working?

Tags: 22.04, autorun

I recently moved from XUbuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Previously on 18.04, when I plugged in an external USB drive containing an `autorun.sh` script, I'd get a pop-up dialog prompting to run that script. This is useful and what I want.

However, on 22.04 I am having trouble with this and need help please.

When I plug the drive in, I get no pop-up dialog. Instead, I need to select *Run Software* from the top. Usability-wise, that's cool except when I click it, nothing happens.

When I click *Run Software*, I get a spinning "busy" icon for 10 seconds or so but my script doesn't get run. I have tried a trivial script for my `autorun.sh` (e.g. `echo "foo" > /tmp/foo.txt`) but no luck. Execute permissions are set.

In my **Settings->Removable Media**, I have tried **Software** set to **Run Software** and **Ask what to do** but both give the same outcome (nothing happens).

Any clues how to troubleshoot this or where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cause here is this bug in GNOME Files (I am running 42.2): https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/2209 This bug very closely matches my experience.

This has been fixed but it will take a little time to get down to Ubuntu I suspect. In the meantime, I am having to manually run (right click, "Run as a program") which works fine.